# How to solve the Problem of login with google in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, web, redirect, callback

Recently I am starting laravel socialite for google. It works for https://wedhow.com but problem in https://www.wedhow.com

As my services file callback code:

```
'google' => [
        'client_id' => '817319187385-458o4s22p1igr44sgeduoh3qcrjb02n9.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'client_secret' => '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',
       'redirect' => 'https://wedhow.com/member/auth/google/callback',
```

Why I try to login with google redirect to:

```
https://wedhow.com/member/auth/google/callback?state=EHDwEGKVgskM0ENz8bCceoeHmdEdp2Kc3Xlo3re0&code=4%2F0ARtbsJrFK7ig33Wc-qpw23r3BfjDazkT51cvn_iT_oSskbk0R6Im2NbgC0KkHm-sybQ8iw&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=none
```

but if I change redirect url in service as well as google developer console  with "https://www.wedhow.com" It works for https://www.wedhow.com but problem in https://wedhow.com

Please help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
=>set your redirect url on your Google Cloud console project go to the Authorised redirect URIs
set this https://wedhow.com/member/auth/google/callback then save check your google with login.
```

Comment: I have already set the redirect url in Google Developer Console Project as well.

Comment: witch package using in laravel